# Django integration with Mako Jinja2 template comparison using : render_to_response. Problem?

Tags: django, testing, django-templates, mako, jinja2

I am using Django to build up my web project. As known that mako and Jinja2 template are faster that the one Django's given, I start finding way to integrate mako and Jinja2 into Django with using the Django's way of render_to_response method. After a lot research, I finally figure out the way to make this happen. However, in my integration, the jmeter's performance is something like Jinja2 (3ms) > Django's template (50ms) > mako (218ms).

If I went wrong with something?....Or pls help to advise some best practice to integrate jinja2 and mako.

Below is the coding ()

Mako2django.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from mysite.settings import TEMPLATE_DIRS 

   def render_to_mako(t,c=None,context_instance=None):
   path = TEMPLATE_DIRS
   makolookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[path],output_encoding='utf-   8',input_encoding='utf-8')
mako_temp = makolookup.get_template(t)
if context_instance:
    context_instance.update(c)
else:
    context_instance = Context(c)
data = {}
for d in context_instance:data.update(d)
return HttpResponse(mako_temp.render(**data))
```

Jinja2django.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from jinja2 import Environment, ChoiceLoader, FileSystemLoader

# Setup environment
default_mimetype = getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE')

# Create the Jinja2 Environment
   env = Environment(
   line_statement_prefix='%',
   line_comment_prefix='##',
   loader=ChoiceLoader([FileSystemLoader(path) for path in getattr(settings,       'TEMPLATE_DIRS', ())]))

def render_to_string(filename, context={}):
   return env.get_template(filename).render(**context)

def render_to_jinja2(filename, context={},mimetype=default_mimetype, request = None):
   if request: context['request'] = request
   return HttpResponse(render_to_string(filename, context),mimetype=mimetype)
```

The view.py is similar as below

```
from draft.jinja2django import render_to_jinja2

def view1(request):
    b = "helloworld"
    return render_to_jinja2('testjinja.html', context={"test":b})
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336713/django-switching-to-jinja2.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Django 1.2 you can create your custom template loader that returns your Template object. Doing that you can make django's render_to_response, render_to_string and counterparts render using your template system.

I am using this one:
https://gist.github.com/972162

It loads Jinja2 templates transparently and falls back to Django templates for admin, contrib and third-party apps.