# Object-like website design in Python

Tags: python, html, django, web

There are tools that allow to very easily create a GUI application. For example, wxPython allows me to make a GUI with use of objects called widgets. Can I create a website in a simillar way (it is using widget-like objects)?

```
if yes:
   Can I use this tool with Django?
```

Comment: You can use something like extJs for frontend and django for backend dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would be interested in [Django's HTML templating engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/). With a HTML templating engine you can build blocks (widgets) that you can plug-in wherever you want. You can also use Django's context variables to fill in dynamic content.

I have also heard good things about the [Jinja2 templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), which you can integrate into Django as well. I haven't used Jinja2 but here are some [reasons to make the switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352037/1507867).